# Best way to format a basic PHP website

Tags: php, html, format

So I was wondering what people think is a better method of building a basic PHP website. The two options I have are as follows:

1. www.website.com/index.php or www.website.com/contact-us.php
2. www.website.com/index.php or www.website.com/index?contact-us

So in the first option, There would be separate pages for each page of the website, I would "include()" the header and footer, the rest would be created on that page.

In the second option, there would only be an index page with everything being included()" onto that page depending on the $_GET request. It would look kind of like this

```
<?php include('inc/templates/header.php'); ?>
if(isset($_GET['home'])){
    include("pages/home.php");
}
if(isset($_GET['contact'])){
    include("pages/contact.php");
}
<?php include("inc/templates/footer.php"); ?>
```

Any opinion on the better method?

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for, just trying to see what people do, and maybe why they like doing it that way.

Comment: My point is your question is off-topic, read the [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help article

Comment: I see what you mean, I apologize for posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my opinion, the best approach is to implement the basic HTTP routing. This is a combination of the configuration of the server and request parsing. 
For example, you can use third-party libraries for your application or for inspiration to write own one.

Paths will look like this: 
`site.com/route-name/foo/bar`

As an example, you can look at:

https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router

https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute

very nice implementation of HTTP routing in laravel framework:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.5/src/Illuminate/Routing

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing

Comment: Thanks, I have laravel on a list of things I have to learn, I will look into it, I skimmed your links and I think that is what I am looking for. I will spend some time reading through them.

Comment: @JonW I wish you success in this